# How would I prove what elements $S_3$ contains, and what its subgroups are?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Given that $S_3$ is a symmetric group of size three, how would I find all elements of it, and all subgroups?

Comment: $S_3$ is the group of all permutations of 3 elements --usually {$1,2,3$} , or all bijections from that set to itself.

Comment: $S_3$, as you defined it above is of order $3!=6$. ;-)

Comment: Isn't it of order 3!?

Comment: So is it enough to say it is order 3, then find 6 elements? 
Also, to find subgroups, would I just "guess and check"?

Comment: Well, it is order 6. And the subgroup must have an order that divides the order of the group. Maybe you can look at the multiplication table to find subcollections closed under multiplication.

Comment: Yarg that's that I meant. Why must the subgroup have an order that divides the group order?

Comment: This is Lagrange's Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory). But things become simpler since the identity must be in any subgroup.

Comment: Is there an easier way than using Lagrange's theorem? I'm just starting abstract algebra. I showed the sets up to order 3, but how can I say that there cannot be any of order 4 or 5?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10550/discussion-between-tony-and-dbf)

Comment: I'm very sorry, I must go; it is 4 a.m here. Could you wait until tomorrow? I will gladly chat with you.

Answer (score 2):

It is usual to write elements of $S_{3}$ in one of two forms. As @DBF explained, $S_{3}$ consists of all bijections on the set $\{1,2,3\}$. Thus for an element $\sigma\in S_{3}$ you need to explain where $\sigma$ maps each of $1,2\text{ and }3$. Suppose we have that

$
\sigma:1\longmapsto 2\\
\sigma:2\longmapsto 1\\
\sigma:3\longmapsto 3
$

Then we would write this as

$
\sigma=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}\right)
$

Here the first column above says that $\sigma:1\mapsto 2$, the second column says $\sigma:2\mapsto 1$ and the third column says $\sigma:3\mapsto 3$.

Another way that you could write this is as $\sigma=(1,2)(3)$. This says that sigma maps $1\mapsto2$ and then $2\mapsto 1$, whilst $3\mapsto 3$. This is known as the cycle decomposition of $\sigma$. Don't worry if you find this trickier though. If you are just starting out with abstract algebra it may be best to stick with the first notation. (However, if you want to read more about cycle decomposition, just look in any abstract algebra or group theory textbook.

With the above, you should be able to write out all 6 elements of $S_{3}$.

Now, what do you know about subgroups of a given group? Well they need to be subsets and they need to be groups in their own right. You have four axioms that determine if a non-empty set together with a binary operation (a way of multiplying two elements together - below I've denoted it by $*$) is a group. It must be

1. Closed under the binary operation (so for all $,y$ in your set, both $x*y$ and $y*x$ are in your set).
2. Multiplication must be associative (so for all $x,y,z$ in your set we have the relation $(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)$ - i.e. it doesn't matter where you place the parentheses).
3. There must be an identity element with respect to multiplication (an element $e$ such the $e* x=x=x* e$ for all elements $x$ of your set).
4. Each element of your set must have an inverse with respect to multiplication (so for all $x$ in your set, there exists some $y$ in your set such that $x* y=e=y* x$).

**Aside:** The identity element of a group is unique, and for each $x$ in your set, the inverse will be unique, hence it is usually denoted by $x^{-1}$.

Now returning to $S_{3}$, the elements of $S_{3}$ are bijections and hence are functions, so our binary operation/multiplication is just composition of functions. Also the identity element $e$ will just be the identity function:

$
e=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

For a subset $H\subset S_{3}$ to be a subgroup, by axiom 3 it must contain the identity element $e$. As $S_{3}$ is a group the associativity rule (axiom 2) will automatically hold in any subset of $S_{3}$, so we now just need to check axioms 1 and 4.

I suggest that you try a few examples out to see what is going on - it is the best way to learn. You can check that $\{e\}\subset S_{3}$ satisfies axioms 1 and 4, so it is a subgroup of $S_{3}$. Next take $H_{a}=\{e,\sigma\}$ where $\sigma$ is as defined above. Does this satisfy the axioms 1 and 4? If not, what element can you add so that these axioms are satisfied?

Next take $H_{b}=\{e,\tau\}$ where

$
\tau=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right)
$

Does $H_{b}$ satisfy axioms 1 and 4, and if not, what elements of $S_{3}$ do you need to add to satisfy the axioms?

As others have said, there are many tools such as Lagrange's Theorem that can help you with this, but on a small example such as this, it is probably more beneficial for your understanding to try a few examples.

**SPOILER**

> In the above examples, $H_{a}=\{e,\sigma\}$ is a subgroup of $S_{3}$ as it satisfies axioms 1 and 4. For axiom 1, note that $e*e=e$, $e*\sigma=\sigma$, $\sigma*e=\sigma$ and $\sigma*\sigma=e$. From this we can also see that $e^{-1}=e$ and $\sigma^{-1}=\sigma$. In the second example, $H_{b}$ is not a group as $\tau^{2}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 \end{array}\right)$. However $H_{c}:=\{e,\tau,\tau^{2}\}$ is a subgroup as it is now closed under multiplication (an easy check) and each element has an inverse, namely $e^{-1}=e$, $\tau^{-1}=\tau^{2}$ and $(\tau^{2})^{-1}=\tau$.

Comment: I actually did the work you did in the spoiler to find H2, and H3, but I didn't know about trying H5 or H6, and I was hoping there was a way around it.

Comment: @Tony Sorry my notation has obviously been misleading. By labelling the sets $H_{2}$ and $H_{3}$ I did not mean that they were subgroups of size $2$ and $3$ respectively (I've changed the notation in my answer to $H_{a}$, $H_{b}$ and $H_{c}$ to clarify this). There are actually more subgroups of size $2$ and more of size $3$ that you should look for. In total you will be looking for a total of 7 subgroups.

Comment: The characteristics of those sets describes all sets of those sizes though, doesn't it? Furthermore, I found all subsets, but without checking for subsets of sizes 4 and 5... I just don't know how to definitely say there are no more subsets without checking every single one which seems to be exhausting.

Comment: Indeed the characteristics of those sets does describe all sets of those sizes (in the case of $S_{3}$). For a subset of size 4 or 5, you know that it either contains $\tau$ or $\tau^{2}$ and it also contains an element of order $2$ (something that like $\sigma$ satisfies $\sigma^{2}=e$ - there are three such elements), or it will be equal to the set containing these three elements of order 2 and the identity element $e$. You just need to prove that in each of these cases that for axioms 1 and 4 to be satisfied, every element of $S_{3}$ must be in your subset.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to @David's nice observations indicating any element of $S_3$ can be considered as a on-one function, say $\sigma$, we get the element of $S_3$ as follows:

$$
\{\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 3 & 2 \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 1 & 3 \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 \end{array}\right)\}
$$ which is equivalently be shown as:
$$
\{id, (1)(2,3), (2)(1,3), (3)(1,2), (1,2,3), (1,3,2)\}
$$

According to Lagrange's theorem, if $H$ wants to be a subgroup of $S_3$ so $|H|$ must devide the order of the group which is $6$. This means that: $$|H|=1,~2,~3,6$$ Since $|(1,2)|=|(2,3)|=|(1,3)|=2$ so $$H_1=\{id\},\\H_2=\{\langle(1,2)\rangle\}=\{id,(1,2)\}\\H_3=\{\langle(1,3)\rangle\}=\{id,(1,3)\}\\H_4=\{\langle(2,3)\rangle\}=\{id,(2,3)\}$$ Also, have a looking at two other cycles $ (1,2,3), (1,3,2)$, we see that $$(1,2,3)^2=(1,3,2),~~(1,2,3)^3=id$$ and this means that $(1,2,3)$ is of order $3$ and $H_5=\langle(1,2,3)\rangle=\{id, (1,2,3),(1,3,2)\}$ Henece, adding $G$, as a subgroup of itself we get $$H_1,H_2,H_3,H_4,H_5,G$$

Here, is a computational approach in GAP:

```
gap> LoadPackage("sonata");;
     s:=SymmetricGroup(IsPermGroup,3);;
     e:=Subgroups(s)
     for i in [1..6] do Print(e[i],"~",StructureDescription(e[i]),"\n"); od;
```

---

```
     Group( () )~1
     Group( [ (2,3) ] )~C2
     Group( [ (1,2) ] )~C2
     Group( [ (1,3) ] )~C2
     Group( [ (1,2,3) ] )~C3
     Group( [ (1,3,2), (1,2) ] )~S3
```

Comment: $+1$ for nice expanding the problem. 3 months ending up within a day :D. Hope to have a successful academic year.

Comment: Hello, dear friend, @Babak!

Comment: I miss you around, my friend Babak. Hoping your internet service gets more consistent! ;-)