# Determining all subgroups of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Related to : [How would I prove what elements $S_3$ contains, and what its subgroups are?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490294/how-would-i-prove-what-elements-s-3-contains-and-what-its-subgroups-are)
I don't know Lagrange's theorem, and I don't want to prove that there are **no** subgroups of size $4$ or $5$, is there a better way to argue that there aren't any, with basic abstract algebra knowledge?

Comment: Regardless of whatever answers you may get here: **learn Lagrange's theorem**.

Comment: I will, but for the purposes of my abstract algebra course where we have not learned it as of yet, how would I?

Comment: There are only 6 elements. One of them must be in any subgroup. Take the elements one at a time and see what the smallest subgroup you can make that contains that element is. Then check what happens if you add any extra element to one of those subgroups.